# Ruby on Rails autocomplete gem undefined local variable

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, autocomplete, rubygems

I'm trying to use rails3-jquery-autocomplete gem by CrowdInteractive:
https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/blob/master/README.md

I get this error however: `undefined local variable or method autocomplete_food_long_desc_foods_path' for #<#<Class:0xa17cf00>:0xa5ac724>`

I know this question has been asked before, but I still can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I followed all the instructions in the README, and here is my code:

recipes model:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :foods, :through => :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
end
```

recipe_ingredients join-table model:

```
class RecipeIngredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe, 
  belongs_to :food, :foreign_key = 'ndb_no'
end
```

foods model:

```
class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'foods'
  set_primary_key 'ndb_no'

  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :recipes, :through => 'recipe_ingredients'
end
```

The basic high-level logic is that a recipe has many foods, and foods can belong to several recipes. To do that, I have a join table called recipe_ingredients, which also has a few more important fields.

I want to use autocomplete with my recipes controller to query the foods table and get individual foods.

Recipes controller code:

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  include ApplicationHelper
  include RecipesHelper
  autocomplete :food, :long_desc
end
```

recipes/new renders this partial form:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery', 'nested_form' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "autocomplete-rails.js" %>
<%= f.autocomplete_field :food_long_desc, autocomplete_food_long_desc_foods_path %>
```

Here is my routes file (I have run `rake routes`)

```
resources :recipes do
  get :autocomplete_food_long_desc, :on => :collection
end
```

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In regard or you route the correct URL is :

```
autocomplete_food_long_desc_recipes_path
```

instead of

```
autocomplete_food_long_desc_foods_path
```

Comment: Changed my view `<%= f.autocomplete_field :food_long_desc, autocomplete_food_long_desc_recipes_path %>` but no such luck.